# Simple singularly perturbed systems

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

I'm an engineer looking for math insights into an engineering problem. I have a simple first order ODE:  $$\dot x(t)=k\Big(-x(t)+f(t)\Big).$$ As you can see, this system behaves like a low-pass filter with $k$ acting as the filter bandwidth. The higher the filter bandwidth, the higher frequency can pass through the filter. So by hand waving, I thought when the bandwidth is very very high, almost everything passes through the filter and $x(t)$ will behave like $f(t)$. I did many Simulink runs as well as experiments with an RC circuit and a function generator that produces different signals $f(t)$. My hand-waving statement seems to be true. My questions are:

1) How do I rigorously show that as $k\to \infty,$ $x(t)$ behaves like $f(t)$?

2) I did some literature review and figured that the statement is true if $f(t)$ is constant in light of Tikhonov's result [1]. I wanted to dig deeper into the literature, but my background in maths is too limited to understand deeper results. If the statement is not true in general, what is the condition on $f(t)$ for the statement to be true?

Any ideas or discussions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

[1] A.N. Tikhonov, Systems of differential equations containing a small parameter multiplying the derivative, Mat. Sb. 31 (1952) pp. 575-586

Comment: I suppose it should be $-x$ in your ODE. Else it is not stable neither you have low pass filter behavior

Comment: My bad! I have edited the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to 1):
A singular perturbation is a degeneration of the systems order, i.e. the derivative is perturbed.

Write the ODE in standard form for singularly perturbed systems:

$\frac{1}{k} \dot x = -x + f(t)$

or with $\varepsilon=1/k$

$\varepsilon \dot x = -x + f(t)$ .

Now, let $k \to \infty$:

$0=-x+f(t)$

$x=f(t)$ is called a quasi steady state.

It follows: $x=f(t) + O(\varepsilon)$. The last expression is a result of Tikhonov. It means that it is an approximation with error of order $ O(\varepsilon)$.

2) $f(t)$ must be a unique root of the degenerate system. This is the case in this example. Furthermore Tikhonov’s Thm requires some stability conditions of the so called boundary layer model. To consider this, set $y=x-f$ and insert it in the ODE:

$\varepsilon \dot y =  -y - \varepsilon \dot f(t)$ and set $\tau= t/\varepsilon$:

$\frac{d}{d\tau}y=-y -\varepsilon \dot f(t)$ and let $\varepsilon=0$:

$\frac{d}{d\tau}y=-y $.

This is the boundary layer system which describes the fast transient before reaching the quasi steady state.

It is exponentially stable. Hence, due to Tikhonov‘s Thm the approximation 
 $x=f(t) + O(\varepsilon)$ is valid.

Comment: I have corrected the typo in the question. Could you please edit your answer accordingly so I can follow. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, just edited. I also edited a typo, the derivative of $f$ in the boundary layer model. It can be seen that $f$ also must be differentiable or not varying too fast

Comment: @KimGasko : please tell me if any points should be further clarified or explained in more detail

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It's much clearer to me now. It appears from your answer that the boundary layer system, which represents Tikhonov’s stability condition, is constructed after taking the limit $\epsilon\to0$ (that's why you $\epsilon$ is set to $0$ to obtain $\frac{d}{d\tau}y=-y$). Can you please confirm that this agrees with Tikhonov’s analysis?

Comment: You’re welcome, yes it is. This is actually done to show that the trajectory really approach the steady state as $\varepsilon\to0$. The $\tau$ can be considered as a fast time scale, i.e all functions in $t$ appear as frozen.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question: When you set $\tau=t/\epsilon$, doesn't the ODE become: $\frac{d}{d\tau}y=-y -\frac{d}{d\tau} f$?

Comment: Finally, it yields the same, since $f$ is a function of $t$

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it now. This is where I thought $f$ has to be a constant. But in light of your answer, $f$ can be any function as long as it is smooth enough.